# Visual Designer Tool for Hibernate Annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations, hibernate-tools

I started using Hibernate only recently. While I was playing with it, I experienced the problem , which I assume, is faced by every Hibernate Beginner.

I want a good visual designer Tool that can generate Annotated Classes for Hibernate. It should be able to generate the classes from some diagramatic representation or a wizard. I would prefer the Tool to be Free and Open Source but that is not a compulsion.

Are there any such Hibernate Annotated Class Generator Visual Tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you'll get with Open Source Tools is probably [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools). It contains some [Eclipse Plugins](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.2.0.GA/en/hibernatetools/html/plugins.html) for [Mapping Diagrams](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.2.0.GA/en/hibernatetools/html/plugins.html#map_diagram) etc.

Comment: From the link, Mapping Diagrams appear to be sort of **read-only** type where we can see the representation but can't modify it to generate the classes :(

Comment: @Lucky exactly. Round-trip engineering is only available in commercial tools AFAIK

Comment: Are you aware of any commercial tools? {commercial is also fine for now}

Comment: @Lucky I've never tried any myself, but I have heard people recommend this: http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/dbva/

Comment: It supposedly has Java round-trip engineering: http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/dbva/provides/codedbeng.jsp#javaroundtrip